# toDate with .utc is using local timezone

Tags: javascript, momentjs

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/

```
moment.utc(ts).format(); // 2018-10-25T05:00:00+00:00
moment.utc(ts).toDate(); // Thu Oct 25 2018 07:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
```

How do I get the toDate format of the date but lose the local timezone (so that the second line displays 05:00:00 GMT+0000 (Central European Summer Time)). I thought using ".utc" fixed this?

Comment: Are you looking for `moment.utc(ts).format('ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]Z')`? Simply have a look at [`format`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) docs.

Comment: @VincenzoC Very close! But not the same:
`Thu Sep 27 2018 14:00:00 GMT+00:00` vs. `Thu Sep 27 2018 16:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)`

Comment: I fear that you can't get something like _Central European Summer Time_ using momentjs (even if you use moment-timezone). I think that the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41591377/4131048) could be useful.

Comment: @VincenzoC I just realised that it is the Javascript Date object format so you are indeed correct.